# streaming a full screen app or a screen space on apple TV

Tags: appletv, macos

I would like to see if there is a possibility of streaming a full screen app or a space onto Apple TV with MacOS mountain lion. The implication of this is that I could stream for example a tech talk on to my TV while I browse on another screen space. I believe that mirroring would just show the stuff that I see on my screen.

Comment: Mountain Lion hasn't released yet, so most of us aren't running the OS to help solve your issue.  Even anyone who is already running Mountain Lion is probably violating an NDA by talking about it.  So, you'll have to wait until after the Mountain Lion launch to see if this is possible (or if there is a hack to do it).

Comment: Our policy is to avoid questions about software until it's released, so I'm closing this for now. We can reopen soon when ML is released.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a hack will be  possible or Apple will have an AirPlay API for someone to make an application that makes the Apple TV a 2nd display it does not look possible with the advertised [OS X Mountain Lion feature](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html) AirPlay Mirroring, since it will only allow mirroring of what is on your screen, probably only your primary screen too.

> **Wireless mirroring**
>
> Send what’s on your Mac screen to an HDTV wirelessly with Apple TV. Mirroring is great for classrooms, conference rooms, and your living room.